# Users who do not have Contribute on the root site are not able to run workflow 2013 . Error "Access denied ..."

Tags: sharepoint-online, workflow, permissions, sharepoint-designer-workflow

I have the following case inside our SharePoint online root site collection:

1. Members SP Group >> with Contribute permissions >> contain only UserA & UserB
2. Readers SP Group >> with Read permissions >> Contain Everyone except external
3. Inside the root site, we have a custom list which have a unique permissions (Contribute for all), where it got this permission:-

   - Members Group >> with Contribute permissions >> contain only UserA & UserB
   - Readers Group >> with Contribute permissions >> Contain Everyone except external
4. this custom list has a list workflow 2013 which get triggered when items are added and modified.

now if userC (who is a reader on the root site and contributor on the list), create a new item inside the custom list, then the workflow 2013 will raise this error:

> Activity in progress
>
> Retrying last request. Next attempt scheduled in less than one minute.
>   Details of last request: HTTP Forbidden to
>   https://*******.sharepoint.com/_api/web/lists(guid'95f1cccb-8f6f-46f6-89c8-91046a3436cd')/Items
>   Correlation Id: 4590651d-d586-53c6-a024-6fe29fbc91a7 Instance Id:
>   d19ac710-3665-4bdc-b4fb-d437e8877a9c
>
> Access denied. You do not have permission to perform this action or
>   access this resource.

so why is this happening? now if i grant userC contribute on the root, the workflow will run without errors... but i do not want userC to have contribute on the root site

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Cause**

Workflow is throwing this error because your end user is not having permission on a list whose GUID is `95f1cccb-8f6f-46f6-89c8-91046a3436cd`.

Probably this list is the workflow history or workflow task list associated with your workflow OR any other list you are using in your workflow actions.

**Solution**:

1. Identify the list with GUID `95f1cccb-8f6f-46f6-89c8-91046a3436cd` in your SharePoint site.
2. Grant the permissions to the end users on this list.

Comment: @Genesh Sanap thanks for the valuable feedback , this list if the "workflow history" list...